# MySQL - How to create a composite table?

Tags: mysql, database, command

I am new to MySQL, I am about creating a database that manages information about diabetes patients. I have 6 tables, what important for here is 3 tables, `diabetic` table, `diabetic_profile` table and `medication_profile` table.

The last table (`medication_profile`) should be a composite table, which will have two primary foreign keys. These foreign keys are the `diabetic_id`(`diabetic`) and the `profile_id` (`diabetic_profile`). Translating that into MySQL code is the difficult part for me. I tried many ways but couldn't yet achieve that. below is the sql command I used:

```
CREATE TABLE Medication_Profile (
    medication_type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    profile_id INT NOT NULL,
    diabetic int NOT NULL,
    times_a_day NUMERIC(1) NOT NULL,
    dose VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (medication_type, profile_id, diabetic),
    FOREIGN KEY (profile_id, diabetic)
    REFERENCES Diabetic_Profile (profile_id, diabetic_id)

);
```

please notice that the diabetic_id in this table is already a foreign key exists in Diabetic_profile table.

So any suggestions you may provide, please?

thanks in advance

Comment: when I remove the diabetic foreign column, the code runs properly. so I think there is an issue with the referencing but couldn't figure that out yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need a separate `FOREIGN KEY` clause for each foreign key, since they refer to different tables.

```
FOREIGN KEY (diabetic_id) REFERENCES diabetic (diabetic_id),
FOREIGN KEY (profile_id) REFERENCES diabetic_profile (profile_id)
```